# Unable to access Azure VM remotely on port 80

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am unable to access/telnet using the public IP on port 80.

I am able to access the it from inside the VM.

The port has been added to the inbound rules in Azure dashboard:

[image: Network rules]

[image: VM Firewall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the issue was due to the Windows firewall rule being misconfigured. It should allow access from any address, instead of local subnet.